# Adding AdMob to code generated from PWA Builder

Tags: android, admob, progressive-web-apps, trusted-web-activity, pwabuilder

I have an PWA application which I export to TWA (Trusted Web Activity) and want to put it into Play Store,
so I use PWA Builder [www.pwabuilder.com](http://www.pwabuilder.com) (It uses Bubblewrap under the hood) and there is a possibility to download source code.
I follow guide how to integrate AdMob from official website https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start
But I cannot find AppCompatActivity class in the sourcecode, where should I put the code displayed here
https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start#example_mainactivity_excerpt

Or if anyone successfully integrated AdMob to its PWA(TWA) app, I would be gratefull for tips.
Thanks!

I've tried to add it here:

in `main` -> `java` -> `app.app-name.twa` folder

`public class Application extends android.app.Application`

because it looked the most similar but I still cannot see the add is showing